# How to get the continent in the request header for cloudfront in Lambda Edge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

For the country code I can use header cloudfront-viewer-country.

That's great but I need to get the continent too.

Is there a feature for Cloudfront to add this to header? otherwise I will have to translate country code to continent myself.

### Edit

Currently I have my function to a lookup in a hard-coded map of countries to continents which is not great. I could find no built-in way to do this otherwise.

Comment: Don't believe this mapping is available but maybe you could use Lambda@Edge and inject the continent using a simple ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country to continent mapping.

Comment: thats what im doing now. the only other way would be to read the IP and try to use a geo lookup service/library. are these the only options? Route53 has a mapping of country codes to continents can this be leveraged? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-geo.html#rrsets-values-geo-alias.

Comment: I'm not immediately aware of any options here.

Comment: hmm could I use route53 like a sort of authoritative resource for figuring out what country code belongs to which continent? I guess that doesn't change frequently- if ever. a static map is fine. Im surprised the state dept or something doesnt publish that somewhere